# Triggering a javascript event to display error text on an another div with an ajax response

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am facing a strange problem with JavaScript, I am working on an ajax database. The login form of the Database sends the data to the PHP controller with an ajax request/function. I have an error-displayer invisible div(named errorDiv) on the login page. errorDiv html is:

```
<div id="errorDiv" style="visibility:hidden; display:none">
...
</div>
```

When both the username and password fields in the login form are left empty, I need the PHP controller to response, show the login form and run a JavaScript function "DisplayLoginError()" which will make the error div visible and display the error message(please fill both the fields) in the error-div.DisplayLoginError() function's code is:

```
function DisplayLoginError()
{
document.getElementById('errorDiv').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('errorDiv').style.display="block";
document.getElementById('errorDiv').innerHTML = "<?php echo $loginerror; ?>";
}
```

The php controller code is:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['login']))
{
if(isset($_REQUEST['username']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']))
    {
    .....Both the fields are filled...
    }
else   /*===Error:Any of the username or password field has  been left empty====*/
    {
    $loginerror='Please fill both the Fields to login.';
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\hospital\includes\collegedata\login-form.html.php';
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that it can't be done as most javascript events are user-action-triggered. For the time-being I have assigned the form tag a mouseover event which when triggered run the DisplayLoginError function and displays the error in the errorDiv.

```
<form onmouseover="DisplayLoginError()"> ..... </form>
```

But its not the proper solution. I need an event which can run this function while loading only the login div not the whole page. I can't use the onload event here as its an ajax Database where the main page remains still only div's change. May be the time events can be used for this purpose... I am not sure...May be there is some better solution... How can I do it with ajax?

Comment: why can't u just use submit.click()

Comment: @Napster it's not during submission. Its about response. When the php controller is responding to the error it should also display the error on the errorDiv with the response.

Comment: If this is AJAX, then there should be some client-side script which will process the response. Use that. I'm not sure what your "php controller code" is doing, but it doesn't look like it's sending a response to be processed at the client.

Comment: You can use blur() in jquery which works when the textbox losts focus.

Comment: @nithi hmm Please suggest a javascript solution. Or if I could add a javascript line of code on the main page which can trigger the function  DisplayErrorText(); with a javascript time event after some milliseconds. Kindly guide me about how to use Javascript time event for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lost focus event in javascript. I can't understand your query clearly. So this is just a suggestion.

```
<div id='errorDiv' >
</div>
Username : <input type="text" name="username" id="uname" onBlur="checkUsername();">
Password : <input type="text" name="password" id="pword" onBlur="checkValues();">

<script type="text/javascript">
function checkValues()
{
    uname = document.getElementById('uname').value;
    pword = document.getElementById('pword').value;
    if(uname=="" || pword=="") {
        document.getElementById('errorDiv').innerHTML="Please fill both the fields";
    }else{
        document.getElementById('errorDiv').innerHTML="";
    }
}
function checkUsername()
{
    uname = document.getElementById('uname').value;
    if(uname==""){
        document.getElementById('errorDiv').innerHTML="Please enter username";
    }else{
        document.getElementById('errorDiv').innerHTML="";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution I am going to check it and tell you about the outcome.

Comment: Thanks its working great. However its being done on the client side. I actually wanted to do it with ajax.responseText( i am voting for you as thanks). So that the server may send some lines of javascript code (to the client browser) which will do the same thing as this code is doing, but doing it that way looks really difficult. Thanks for the great answer. Kindly let me know if this can also be done with ajax responseText?